# DNS Hostname resolv problem

Tags: linux, debian, dns, hostname

My linux server that i set up earlier won't resolv by hostname :
i can't access on ssh or on website (port 80,8834) via the hostname but only via IP

my /etc/hosts file is well configured i think :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
ip_server name_server.domain.corp name_server
```

my resolv.conf is :

```
nameserver ip_dns_server_dc01
nameserver ip_dns_server_dc02
search domain.corp
```

Please someone could help me ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2):

Per `man resolv.conf`, the syntax of the `nameserver ...` line is:

```
       nameserver Name server IP address
              Internet address of a name server  that  the  resolver  should
              query,  either  an  IPv4 address (in dot notation), or an IPv6
              address in colon (and possibly dot) notation as per RFC  2373.
              Up  to MAXNS (currently 3, see <resolv.h>) name servers may be
              listed, one per keyword.  If there are multiple  servers,  the
              resolver  library  queries  them  in  the order listed.  If no
              nameserver entries are present, the default is to use the name
              server  on the local machine.  (The algorithm used is to try a
              name server, and if the query times out, try the  next,  until
              out  of  name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers
              until a maximum number of retries are made.)
```

Basically, all of these lines:

```
nameserver ip_dns_server_dc01
nameserver ip_dns_server_dc02
nameserver dns_service (AD-DC 01)
nameserver dns_service (AD-DC 02)
```

are invalid because `ip_dns_server_dc01` is not an IPv4 address (in dot notation) or an IPV6 address (in colon notation).

I suspect the file you have is copied from some instructions where you were intended to replace `dns_server` with the IP address of `DC 01`.

It should look something like:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1 
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1111
```

---

You've edited your question from `nameserver dns_service (AD-DC 01)` to `nameserver ip_dns_server_dc01`.  This answer still applies.  But with this new `resolv.conf`, you are a little closer because now you have a single parsable name that could be replaced with an IP.  If you know the IP address of `ip_dns_service_dc01`, you may be able to add `192.168.1.1 ip_dns_service_dc01` to your `/etc/hosts` to make this work where `192.168.1.1` is the IP of the server.  Though, if you have the IP, you should really just put it in `resolv.conf`.